# Java method being called, but elements not displaying in GUI

Tags: java, button, user-interface

I have the following Java method, which I am trying to use to add some buttons to a GUI:

```
private void addButtons(){
    JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");
    JButton saveBtn = new JButton("Save");

    addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            /*Code to be added here */
        }
    });
    addBtn.setBounds(1150, 135, 30, 15);

    saveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            /*Code to be added here */
        }
    });
    saveBtn.setBounds(1190, 135, 30, 15);
System.out.println("'addButtons()' method is being called");
}
```

I am calling this method from a `private void initialize()` method in the same class. I know that `initialize()` is being called because all of the other method calls that it performs are happening, and displaying in the GUI.

However, for some reason, the buttons that I am trying to create and add to my GUI with this method are not being displayed...

Can anyone point out to me why this is, and what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**

Apologies- I'm calling the method in a `private void initialize()` method in the same class:

```
private void initialize(){
    ...
    (other code that is successfully adding stuff to the GUI)
    ...
    addButtons();
}
```

I am seeing the `System.out.println()` message from the end of the `addButtons()` method in the console when I click the button that calls the `initialize()` method... and all of the other code from the `initialize()' method is being called (for example, it's opening a new window, and adding some text, textboxes and tables to the window)...

**Edit 26/06/2014 @ 09:15**

The class where I have written this code extends `JPanel`:

```
public class JConfigurationPane extends JPanel implements UndoableEditListener, ChangeListener
```

I am now no longer using the `addButtons()` method that I had previously mentioned, and am trying to use my `initialize()` method to add the buttons to the JPanel:

```
public void initialize(){
    // Code that initialises other elements in the GUI, such as Jlabels, layout, etc

    JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");
    JButton saveBtn = new JButton("Save");

    this.add(addBtn);
    this.add(saveBtn);
}
```

But the buttons still don't appear when I run the application, even though all of the other graphical elements in the `initialize()` method do... Any ideas why this is? I've added some debug before and after where I create the buttons, and where I add them to the GUI- the debug is displayed in the console, so the code to create and add the buttons must be called...

Comment: Can you post your initialize method as well where you call this addButton(), could be a problem there

Comment: Don't use the setBounds() method. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size/location of a component. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you adding these buttons to the form?

You are creating buttons in the method yes, and attaching listeners to these but the buttons themselves aren't being added to the form which is why you cant see them.

e.g you should be doing something like:

```
yourForm.add(addBtn);
yourForm.add(saveBtn);
```

or add these to a JPanel or something - finally making sure you add this JPanel

Comment: I just thought it might be something along those lines... I tried editing my `initialize()` method to include: `JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");`, etc, and then `this.add(addBtn);`, etc... but I still don't see those buttons in the window...

Comment: Did you remove the calls to setBounds()? - perhaps you're moving the buttons to a location not visible on the form.

Comment: @someone2088, you have been given a link to the Swing tutorial which provides working examples. Start with a working example and customize your code. Also, when you post a question you should include a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem if the tutorial doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, I have removed the calls to `setBounds()`... I added the code to show where I'm trying to add the buttons to the GUI.

Comment: Ok, managed to sort it- I needed to add the calls to `setBounds()` back in, underneath where I was creating the buttons.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve this by moving the code from my `addButtons()` method to my `initialize()` method, and setting the bounds of each button immediately after creating it:

```
JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");
addBtn.setBounds(1000, 135, 75, 25);
```

Comment: -1, did you not read the comment. You should NOT be using setBounds. There is no reason to use setBounds. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers, for too many reasons to be listed here.

Comment: I did read the comment. The fact is that I tried what you suggested, and it didn't work- but adding the `setBounds()` where I've indicated in my answer did work, and I can now see the buttons in my GUI.

Comment: Using setBounds() is NOT the solution. The suggestion I gave you is the proper solution. If is doesn't work then you didn't do it properly, but we can't help because you did not post a proper SSCCE.